# UPDATE: How to return result of Promise with a custom Blazor event javascript (not async)?

Tags: javascript, promise, blazor

Final? Update: Solution 1:  I changed func1 to NOT return a value back to my javascript event, but instead to return the value directly to my calling method using

```
return DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('AppWASM', 'SetImageData', result);
```

from func1 (so I also changed invoke of func1(file) to not assign to a variable).  However, the limitation that the method had to be static had me going in circles.  I could have used this to save it directly to my database but from the app's standpoint that wasn't a good solution.

Final Solution: I saved the value to local storage via

```
 localStorage.setItem("thisimage", result);
```

which is in my revised code, below.  For this app, that makes the most sense since the idea is to hold the image to see if the user wants to save it (or not). So I think I kind of got around the Promise confusion by just going a different route - which is what I found in the similar questions. The code (and image below) shows the value stored in localstorage.
=================================================================**
1st Update: I revised my code to return the Promise eventArg as a JsonDocument (property set as public object Promise {get; set;} in my eventargs class). How do I extract the data from this Promise in C#?  The json document returned does not have a Promise.result element.

I know there are similar questions - scripts can log the result of a Promise to the console, but the returned result is undefined - but the answers are to call the promise function from an async function (and many answers have comments that they don't work). Since my "calling" script is for an event, I don't see how to make it async. So event execution continues without waiting for the result. I've tried assigning to a top level variable with same result. The custom event is fired by a browser event, and the args are returned to a method in the razor page.  I'd like to send imageB64string (or globalimagevar) as a return arg. This is for Net6 Blazor WASM (and Server once it works) apps.

```js
async function func1(fileParam) {
    await blobToBase64(fileParam).then(result => {
        localStorage.setItem("thisimage", result);
        return;
    });
}

async function blobToBase64(blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return await new Promise((resolve, _ ) => {
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            resolve(reader.result);};});}

Blazor.registerCustomEventType("pastemultimedia", {
    browserEventName: 'paste', createEventArgs: event => {
        let isMultimedia = false;
        let data = event.clipboardData.getData('text');
        let promise = "";
        
        const items = event.clipboardData.items;
        const acceptedMediaTypes = ["image/png"];

        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            const file = items[i].getAsFile();

            if (!file) { continue; }
            if (!items[i].type.includes('image')) { continue; }
            if (acceptedMediaTypes.indexOf(items[i].type) === -1) { continue; }

            isMultimedia = true;
            const url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            data = url.createObjectURL(file);

            func1(file);
        }
        return { isMultimedia, data };
     }
})
```

[image]Promise result as json (partial shown):

[image]

Oriignal Result / execution continued before promise was resolved:
imageB64string is: function toString() { [native code] }

ImagePasteEvent.js:40 globalimagevar is:

ImagePasteEvent.js:5 logged from func1: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAVEAAAHaCAYAAAC5AXpZAAAgAElEQVR4nO3df3xU9YHv/xfJYZiEiTNhJmbCBJliiMFgDBo2CroGBbGyUlqxtqDfsqU+9F573W6rbRd7v9r7uHXd1nZdv2VXH1y37u1qa6tbyi60FCpxKWiWKJESDRBoEEISMyETMwzDMAnfP2byexICn0B....

Note: Credit for the base code for the pastemultimedia event to [Felipe Gavilan blog](https://gavilan.blog/2021/05/08/blazor-net-6-custom-events-pasting-images-like-on-twitter-asp-net-core-6/)

Comment: Have you tried `createEventArgs: async event => { ....` and then `await func1(.....)`?

Comment: It is not possible. `createEventArgs` *must* be a synchronous function, so you should have it return a *promise* as event argument (`imageB64string` would be more like `imageB64stringPromise`). It is then the responsibility of the event consumer to await this promise to resolve.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. I made changes as noted above. How can I get either the status (pending/resolved/rejected) or the resolved value from inside my c# method?

Comment: `.createObjectURL()` and `.readAsDataURL()` do the same thing. Why are you using both?

Comment: @Tomalak .createObjectURL creates the blob object I use as img src to display the image on the razor page. That happens immediately  .readAsDataURL returns the binary64 string to store the image in the database, that takes longer - does not complete before the other arguments are returned - and so I had to use the promise to wait for it.  (The images small screenshot snips, so the binary is relatively small).

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it seems like this functionality is already baked into .NET 6.  MS has provided [examples of uploading a blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly) (or file) for both Blazor wasm and server.  The examples don't provide a nice image preview like your code, but I'm sure that could be added.

Comment: The core take-away is: There are no "non-async" promises. That's a contradiction in terms. You cannot return the "finished value" from your event when the value you're interested in is being produced by an asynchronous function. No amount of global variables and extra functions with `async`/`await` will help. As trincot says, the only thing you can do is return the promise and wait for it (either with `await`, or with `.then()`) in the event handler.